# npm ssl3 error: cannot install npm modules

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules, node-gyp

Working on an project that uses frontend-maven-plugin to build and angular app. The plugin does install node (6.10.2) and npm (6.10.0) in a first phase and later it tries to get npm packages and there it fails with SSL error:

```
[INFO] Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/win32-x64-48_binding.node
[ERROR] Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/win32-x64-48_binding.node":
[ERROR]
[ERROR] write EPROTO 101057795:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:2032:
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
[ERROR]       try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.
[ERROR]
[ERROR]       export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234
[ERROR]
[ERROR] or configure npm proxy via
[ERROR]
[ERROR]       npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
[INFO]
[INFO] > node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\node-sass
[INFO] > node scripts/build.js
[INFO]
[INFO] Building: C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node\node.exe C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
[ERROR] gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
[ERROR] gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node\\node.exe',
[ERROR] gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
[ERROR] gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
[ERROR] gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
[ERROR] gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
[ERROR] gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
[ERROR] gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
[ERROR] gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
[ERROR] gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
[ERROR] gyp info using node@6.10.2 | win32 | x64
[ERROR] gyp verb command rebuild []
[ERROR] gyp verb command clean []
[ERROR] gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
[ERROR] gyp verb command configure []
[ERROR] gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2.7" in the PATH
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2.7
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed  python2.7 { Error: not found: python2.7
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2.7\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)',
[ERROR] gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
[ERROR] gyp verb could not find "python2.7". checking python launcher
[ERROR] gyp verb check python launcher python executable found: "C:\\Users\\userx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python27\\python.exe"
[ERROR] gyp verb check python version `C:\Users\userx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print "2.7.0
[ERROR] gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
[ERROR] gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 6.10.2
[ERROR] gyp verb command install [ '6.10.2' ]
[ERROR] gyp verb install input version string "6.10.2"
[ERROR] gyp verb install installing version: 6.10.2
[ERROR] gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
[ERROR] gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 6.10.2
[ERROR] gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created C:\Users\userx\.node-gyp\6.10.2
[ERROR] gyp verb created nodedir C:\Users\userx\.node-gyp\6.10.2
[ERROR] gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.10.2/node-v6.10.2-headers.tar.gz
[ERROR] gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
[ERROR] gyp verb command remove [ '6.10.2' ]
[ERROR] gyp verb remove using node-gyp dir: C:\Users\userx\.node-gyp
[ERROR] gyp verb remove removing target version: 6.10.2
[ERROR] gyp verb remove removing development files for version: 6.10.2
[ERROR] gyp ERR! configure error
[ERROR] gyp ERR! stack Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:04091068:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:bad signature:openssl\crypto\rsa\rsa_sign.c:278:
[ERROR] gyp ERR! stack 101057795:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:2032:
[ERROR] gyp ERR! stack
[ERROR] gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
[ERROR] gyp ERR! stack     at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:804:14)
[ERROR] gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
[ERROR] gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
[ERROR] gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node_modules\node-sass
[ERROR] gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.2
[ERROR] gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
[ERROR] gyp ERR! not ok
[ERROR] Build failed with error code: 1
```

On the above logs it seems also to complain about python but that is wrong while python 2.7 is installed and in path especially for this purpose:

```
python --version
Python 2.7
```

Also I have installed Visual Studio and tried what is found here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Also any try to manually install any npm package fails with same error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '--add-python-to-path=true',
1 verbose cli   '--debug',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--global',
1 verbose cli   'windows-build-tools' ]
2 info using npm@6.10.0
3 info using node@v6.10.2
4 verbose npm-session 46042dcdb191932d
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for windows-build-tools@latest request to https://registry.npmjs.org/windows-build-tools failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:2032:
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 78ms
10 verbose type system
11 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/windows-build-tools failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:2032:
11 verbose stack
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
11 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
11 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)
11 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
11 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
11 verbose stack     at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:346:10)
11 verbose stack     at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:364:5)
11 verbose stack     at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:90:5)
11 verbose stack     at fireErrorCallbacks (net.js:471:13)
11 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.Socket._destroy (net.js:512:3)
11 verbose stack     at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:806:10)
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\userx\git\angular-webapp\war-angular\src\main\ng\node
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
14 verbose argv "C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\userx\\git\\angular-webapp\\war-angular\\src\\main\\ng\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--add-python-to-path=true" "--debug" "install" "--global" "windows-build-tools"
15 verbose node v6.10.2
16 verbose npm  v6.10.0
17 error code EPROTO
18 error errno EPROTO
19 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/windows-build-tools failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:2032:
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: What angular version are we talking about here? Node 6 is very very old..

Comment: I know the entire stack is very old but this is an old app and nobody wants to update it... angular is at 5.2.0